# Remove subdomains from URI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri

I want to remove subdomain names from a URI.

Example: 
I want to return 'baseurl.com' from the Uri "subdomain.sub2.baseurl.com".

Is there a way of doing this using URI class or is Regex the only solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Technically the "top level" in your example is .com, toplevel is a sub-domain of .com, as such the subset of the domain you are looking to extract is pretty much arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I presume that Regex is therefore the only way to go here?

Comment: I think regex is probably your best bet yes.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I have updated my question with the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get it done:

```
var tlds = new List<string>()
{
    //the second- and third-level TLDs you expect go here, set to null if working with single-level TLDs only
    "co.uk"
};

Uri request = new Uri("http://subdomain.domain.co.uk");
string host = request.Host;
string hostWithoutPrefix = null;

if (tlds != null)
{
    foreach (var tld in tlds)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex($"(?<=\\.|)\\w+\\.{tld}$");
        Match match = regex.Match(host);


        if (match.Success)
            hostWithoutPrefix = match.Groups[0].Value;
    }
}

//second/third levels not provided or not found -- try single-level
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hostWithoutPrefix))
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=\\.|)\\w+\\.\\w+$");
    Match match = regex.Match(host);


    if (match.Success)
        hostWithoutPrefix = match.Groups[0].Value;
}
```

Comment: @holex that wasn't the point of the problem the OP presented. But this code could be easily modified to do that.

Comment: what I have been actually referring was that your code is not removing the sub-domains correctly at all – therefore your code is incorrect.

Comment: @holex. On vacation will test and adjust when I'm home.

Comment: Just tested, and works perfectly with OPs requirement. As can be seen here, http://rextester.com/ABMY57739. Now please leave this alone.

Comment: sure thing. I will leave the incorrect answer here. -1, of course, until you fix it  and the algorithm identifies the `subdomain.domain.co.uk` addresses correctly and will present the following and correct input like `domian.co.uk`, not only the `co.uk` – which is absolutely incorrect in this case.

Comment: That ISN'T the OPs question man. I do not understand why you're picking on this answer.

Comment: let me quote the request for you: _"Remove subdomains from URI, I want to remove subdomain names from a URI."_ etc, etc, etc... good luck.

Comment: You know as well as I do that with the opportunity for second- and third-level domains that this is virtually impossible without either brute-forcing (using a TLD list like: https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) or at least having some context which TLDs your dealing with. Given I can't see a situation where the context is completely unknown. I have modified my answer to allow for user input of the known TLDs.

Comment: @holex I would appreciate it if you would remove your -1 here. Having now provided a workaround to your use-case.