# How to loop through links in a web page to find all web pages that are a part of the website?

Tags: c#, loops, web, html-agility-pack, html

I am trying to find all web pages that are a part of a website. For example with the input "www.microsoft.com", I want it to return a list that contains:

- https://www.microsoft.com
- https://support.microsoft.com
- https://www.microsoft.com/windows

But not anything out of a website that is NOT a part of the website given, like https://www.python.org

This is what I am using so far to find ANY webpages, that are connected to a url, using HTML-Agility-Pack:

```
class CheckWebPages
{
    public string url;
    private HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlCode;
    public List<string> webpages;

    public void Start(string address)
    {
        url = address;
        Navigate(url);
    }
    //Navigate to url
    private void Navigate(String address)
    {
        //Format url
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return;
        if (address.Equals("about:blank")) return;
        if (!address.StartsWith("http://") && !address.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            address = "http://" + address;
        }
        try
        {
            url = address;
        }
        catch (System.UriFormatException)
        {
            return;
        }
        //Load HTML from formatted URL
        htmlCode = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb().Load(@url);
        //Start Checking Pages
        CheckPages();
    }

    private void CheckPages()
    {
        foreach (var a in htmlCode.DocumentNode.Descendants("a"))
        {
            if (a.Attributes["href"] != null)
            {
                a.Attributes["href"].Value = new Uri(new Uri(url), a.Attributes["href"].Value).AbsoluteUri;
                webpages.Add(a.Attributes["href"].Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I can do but don't know much about:

1. Turn a link like https://www.microsoft.com into a string like ".microsoft.com"
2. Check if href value contains ".microsoft.com" which works both for pages like something.microsoft.com and www.microsoft.com/something and add the results to list, instead of adding all href.
3. Loop through HTML nodes of all new web pages inside the list, just like going through all the web pages of homepage (or any page) given.
4. Add any unique web page to list, and return all web pages that are found.

Found a way to get a substring of the given url and then I check if ["href"].Value contains it by using string.Contains()

```
private string findSubstring(string url)
{
        string substr = "";
        bool add = false;
        foreach(var i in url.ToCharArray())
        {
            if(i == '/')
            {
                add = false;
            }
            if(add)
            {
                substr = substr + i;
            }
            if (i == '.')
            {
                add = true;
            }
        }

        return substr;
}
```

Since webpages that will be used here will be formatted as:

http://something.website.something/something, we just need the ".website.something" part, so it checks until first dot, then until first slash (if there is any) and gets a substring.

I understand that some websites (like this one) doesn't start with www. or something.stackoverflow, so I may find a fix to such examples, but right now it is working as intended.

Now I need to loop through all links there is with this method, and add each to list if the found link doesn't already exist in the list.

Comment: The `Uri` class will help you.

Comment: May I ask how? I am looking at document, all I found is AbsolutePath to complete href links, which is something I was using for incomplete links, which is a thing I was using for another function but forgot to mention. Other than that, I don't understand how it can help with looping through links, checking if they are a part of the main webpage etc.

Comment: If you want to remove subdomains, too, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956164/3181933), otherwise just use `new Uri(url).Host`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to treat the url like a string and just find '.website.net' part from www.website.net. And check every found link if it contains that substring? Since any related page will contain the exact same substring of '.website.net'? So for that, I need to turn a url into a string, delete until until the first instance of a '.', then keep the remaining part, and then continue deleting after a '/' is found, which it may not be. I don't think Uri is really needed here?

Comment: Okay found it, it may not be the most effective way but it works as intended and finds all related links. Now all I have left is to loop through each of these links AND not add any link that already exists.